# Subtracing px from percentage in CSS Calc()

Tags: css

I have a spacer div that needs to be of a variable height, however the calc() function does't seem to be working for subtracting a fixed amount from a 100%.

```
.spacer {
      border: 1px solid red;
      width: 0px;
      float: right;
      height: calc(100% - 56px);
    }
```

Changing height to calc(100px - 56px) does work.

I am using this with straight CSS, no preprocessors.

[JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Mason240/6L0388fv/)

Comment: A floated element is removed from the flow of the page, so it can't calculate a % based height. Can you describe or give us a picture of what kind of layout you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Changing from 100% to 100px works. The layout is in the JSFiddle. Here is another example: http://www.cssdesk.com/bLNWs

Comment: Even it's in `calc()` but percentage height needs to be based on parent's height. You may use `vh` if it's relative to viewport.

Comment: @Mason240 yes, changing from a % to px based height will work. My point is you can't use a % on a floated element. Describe your end goal and we might be able to give you an alternative or workaround.

Comment: It works in this demo, which I am trying to replicate: http://www.cssdesk.com/bLNWs It is using calc(100% - 20em) on a floated element.